# Why do I have so many settings.json in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Windows.

When I do Ctrl+Shift+P and type "settings", the "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" opens a settings.json located in C:/Users/Me/AppData/Roaming/Code/User.

However, the directory my code is in is C:/Downloads. In here, I have a .vscode directory and in there, another settings.json.

In the root directory of my code, I also have other sub-directories, each with their own .vscode (and in there, another settings.json).

I'm trying to change the color scheme of the built-in terminal but when I do `workbench.colorCustomizations` stuff in the `settings.json` that is in AppData, the colors don't seem to be changing.

I think I've messed up my configuration. Should I only have one settings.json? I think all of mine may be interfering with one another?

Comment: The one in appdata is the global one, and the ones in `.vscode` dirs are local overrides for that specific directories. The bulk of your configuration should be in the former.

Comment: Thanks I see. I also realized that to color the terminal output, I had to do something in my `.bash_profile` instead of tweaking VSCode settings. Everything works as I want now!